# Can't edit front page of website

Tags: frontpage

I need to edit the content on the front page of my website, but I can't figure out -where- the front page is stored. [This is the site](http://michaelsenglishschool.com/).

Anything above "ホーム" (the stuff saying business class, kids class, etc) I can't seem to change/find where it is stored on the server.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, some themes have their own setting with options to display additional information on the homepage.

To find out what's being used for the front page, do the following:

- Navigate to Settings > Reading
- Under *Front page displays* it will show which page is being used

[image]

It's hard to determine what your set up is like with the information you've given. Your best bet is to contact the theme's author since they would know what to do. Looking at your `style.css`, this is the author of your theme:

```
Theme Name:Japan
Theme URI:http://www.viewport.co.za
Author:John Mc / Brendan P
Author URI:http://www.viewport.co.za
```

Comment: The theme is using a static home page, and I can edit that but that's only the stuff below ”ホーム” on the website I linked. I can provide any other information needed - I unfortunately can't contact the author atm as time is of the essence!

Comment: Does this theme have a settings page under Appearance > Theme Options?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: this will be using the the Templates, plz check pages, the name of tempalte
for help plz view this http://prntscr.com/dk0x7m